# GWT Parsing string to Date

Tags: java, string, date, gwt

In GWT I'm trying to parse this string

```
String myString = "Thu Jul 11 10:37:45 BST 2013";
```

Like this:

```
DateTimeFormat sdf = DateTimeFormat.getFormat("EEE MM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy");
Date myDate = sdf.parse(myString);
Window.alert(myDate.toString());
```

But I get this error:

```
18:06:12.293 [ERROR] [dialective] Uncaught exception escaped
com.google.gwt.event.shared.UmbrellaException: Exception caught: Exception caught: Thu     Jul 11 10:37:45 BST 2013 

[...]

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Thu Jul 11 10:37:45 BST 2013
at com.google.gwt.i18n.shared.DateTimeFormat.parse(DateTimeFormat.java:1437)
at com.google.gwt.i18n.shared.DateTimeFormat.parse(DateTimeFormat.java:882)
```

Probably the String *"EEE MM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy"* is wrong, but looking at [the documentation](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/i18n/client/DateTimeFormat.html) I can't figure out how to do it correctly.

Thanks!

Comment: The pattern should be `EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy` - three `M`

Comment: Hi @TuanDang, the pattern you propose still gives exactly the same error. Any ideas?

Comment: the documentation says it's lowercase `z` rather than capital if you want to provide timezone as `BST` rather than `+0100`.  Additionally, I'd be surprised if `BST` works.  Have a look at `TimeZone.getAvailableIDs()` and see if it's in there.

Comment: @Mike You can find the document on `datetime` at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: @funkybro you are right about the BST, if I change it to GMT with lowercase `z` as you propose it works. Thanks! @TuanDang thanks for the link!